# Input serial number when running silent installation with Inno Setup?

Tags: windows, inno-setup

Is there any way to let the user enter the serial key for the product when running the (Innosetup) product installer with flags `/SP- /SILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create new command line parameter and pass the serial number in it.

> /SERIAL=12345679

If this parameter is missing then do not allow to continue (show error/correct usage or simply terminate installation).

Comment: and what if someone has got already compiled installer which uses `UserInfoSerial`?

Comment: I think it is possible to check Registry first and use Registry value instead of /SERIAL.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [@Slappy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22189849/25507):

You can use a `/SERIAL=` command line parameter, but InnoSetup doesn't support this as one of its [standard command line parameters](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_setupcmdline.htm), so you'll have to do a bit of Pascal scripting. Something like the following should work.

```pascal
procedure CheckForCommandLineSerial();
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to ParamCount do
  begin
    if (Pos('/serial=', Lowercase(ParamStr(i))) = 1) and (Length(ParamStr(i)) > 8) then
    begin
      WizardForm.UserInfoSerialEdit.Text := Copy(ParamStr(i), 9, Length(ParamStr(i)) - 8);
      exit;
    end
  end;
end;
```

You can call this from your [`InitializeWizard` event function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm).

Comment: @Tlama - Thank you; I didn't realize that that feature was available. In my case, the Pascal script has a couple of advantages: (1) I'm already using Pascal scripting to set the default serial number, so this can integrate. (2) `DefaultUserInfoSerial={param}` means that the command line is ignored if `UsePreviousUserInfo` is enabled and present, and that may not be desirable.