# Inno Setup: How can I give a serial number to installer when I execute it silently in command line?

Tags: inno-setup

As stated in the title, I want to know how I can give a serial number to installer when I execute it silently in command line.

Comment: @Close voters, this is a perfectly valid programming question.

Comment: However [`duplicate`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22169236/960757).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.iss:

```
[Setup]
DefaultUserInfoSerial={param:serialnumber|Default serial}
```

Command line:

```
setup.exe /silent /serialnumber=12345
```

Don't forget about `UsePreviousUserInfo`.

Comment: Nice! I totally forgot on `{param}` constant. I hesitated to change the value of the `DefaultUserInfoSerial` directive since I felt it as *a default value used when...*, but now I see that it's meant to be a *default value that the user will see*.